# How to iterate through a STL set till the second last element?

Tags: c++, stl, c++03

I want to iterate through a **STL set** to do operations on elements **pairwise** in the set. For eg. if set S={1,2,3), I need to be able to check {1,2},{2,3},{1,3}.

So a very **wrong** C++ code for this would be as follows-

```
set<bitset<2501> > arr;
unsigned sz = arr.size();

rep(i,sz-1)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<sz;j++)
    {
        //do processing and in my case is an OR operation
        if(((arr[i])|(arr[j])) == num)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the above wrong code to give you a better idea of what I want to do. 
A better version (should have worked but did not) is as follows-

```
set<bitset<2501> >::iterator secondlast = arr.end();
advance(secondlast,-1);

for(set<bitset<2501> >::iterator it1 = arr.begin();it1!=secondlast;++it1)
{
    for(set<bitset<2501> >::iterator it2 = it1+1;it2!=arr.end();++it2)
    {
        //do processing, I didn't show the OR operation 
    }
}
```

The above code is giving the following errors-

```
error: no match for 'operator+' in 'it1 + 1'|
error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x < __y'|
```

There were a lot of other notes, warnings also but I think the main culprits are these two errors. If you require the whole clipboard of errors, I'll edit it later on your say.

So I can you please solve the errors and help me do what I need to do :)

EDIT:
Even if I remove the inner loop from the code then also I'm getting errors.

```
set<bitset<2501> >::iterator secondlast = arr.end();
advance(secondlast,-1);

for(set<bitset<2501> >::iterator it1 = arr.begin();it1!=secondlast;++it1)
{

}
```

Comment: You may use `std::next` instead of using `it1 + 1`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Let me check once.

Comment: "Compare" them to what? "Check" what?

Comment: Your title and body do not appear to match

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I have edited "compare" to "do operations" in the body. To be exact I want to do OR operation. Also I think the body does give details to the question.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition or maybe my English is weak :(

Comment: Hmm I guess I get it now; the first element of the tuple can't be the final element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following in C++11:

```
std::set<std::bitset<2501>> arr;
std::set<std::bitset<2501>>::iterator end= arr.end();

for(std::set<std::bitset<2501> >::iterator it1 = arr.begin();it1 != end; ++it1)
{
    for(std::set<std::bitset<2501> >::iterator it2 = std::next(it1); it2 != end; ++it2)
    {
        //do processing, I didn't show the OR operation 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to deal with this new error

Comment: @iammangod96 upgrading your compiler so you can use at least C++11. In the meantime, I've added the [c++03] tag to your question (sorry Jarod!)

Answer (score 3):

You are using `operator+` to get the next element through an iterator, use the preincrement operator, `std::advance` or `std::next` instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::set<int> s{1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (std::set<int>::iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i) {
        for (std::set<int>::iterator j = std::next(i); j != s.end(); ++j) {
            cout << *i << " and " << *j << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am using C++ 4.3.2. So auto is not there.

Comment: @Quentin Left over from something else before... Should have removed it

Comment: I don't see how this will reach _(2,3)_?