# How to get the second last element of a set in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, set

Ex;
We write    `for(int i=0;i<(somethin_length)-1;i++)`
How to do so using set?

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44398264/1896169

Comment: But you want do something over all element except the last one or do you want do something over the second last? In second case... what about reverse iterators (`rbegin()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a set, just decrement the end iterator twice.

```
// Check that we have at least two elements first; if we don't have at least
// two then proceeding would cause undefined behavior.
if (some_set.size() >= 2) {
    auto it = some_set.end();
    --it;
    --it;

    // *it now refers to the second-to-last value
}
```

Comment: Or: `auto it = std::prev(some_set.end(), 2);`.

Comment: Alternatively: `auto it = std::next(some_set.end(), -2);`

Comment: Alternatively `auto it = some_set.rbegin(); ++it;`

Comment: @JeJo Hmm, I was assuming that they just wanted to extract the second last value. If they want to iterate to the second last value, then that's a different matter.

Comment: @JeJo I should admit that my suggestion was based on the answer, rather than on the question. The question itself is not very clear. If `it` is used as an upper boundary, I guess you're right. Btw, you can omit `1` in `std::prev`.